# groovy iterate through list of key and value

Tags: groovy

I have this list:

*service_name_status=[a-service=INSTALL, b-service=UPGRADE, C-service=UPGRADE, D-service=INSTALL]*

And I need to iterate through this list so the first element will be the value of a parameter called **"SERVICE_NAME"** and the second element will be the value of a parameter called **"HELM_COMMAND"**,
after asserting those values to the parameters I will run my command that uses those parameters and then continue the next items on the list which should replace the values of the parameters with items 3 and 4 and so on.

So what I am looking for is something like that:

```
def service_name_status=[a-service=INSTALL, b-service=UPGRADE, C-service=UPGRADE, D-service=INSTALL]
def SERVICE_NAME
def HELM_COMMAND
for(x in service_name_status){
    SERVICE_NAME=x(0,2,4,6,8...)
    HELM_COMMAND=x(1,3,5,7,9...)
    println SERVICE_NAME=$SERVICE_NAME
    println HELM_COMMAND=$HELM_COMMAND

}
```

**the output should be:**

SERVICE_NAME=a-service

HELM_COMMAND=INSTALL

SERVICE_NAME=b-service

HELM_COMMAND=UPGRADE

SERVICE_NAME=c-service

HELM_COMMAND=UPGRADE

SERVICE_NAME=d-service

HELM_COMMAND=INSTALL

and so on...

I couldn't find anything that takes any other element in groovy, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is `service_name_status` a String or a List of Strings? Can you edit the example code so that it compiles?

Comment: Could you please provide the actual example of what the problem is and make sure that it works at least to the point where it does not work? Right now this is just full of syntactic errors and it wont parse. At that point it's not even clear if you just have forgot to add the `"` or they got lost along the lines. Your "list" there could be anything from a groovy list with strings in it or some string you have to parse.

Answer (score 0):

The collection you want is a Map, not a List.

Take note of the quotes in the map, the values are strings so you need the quotes or it won't work. You may have to change that at the source where your data comes from.

I kept your all caps variable names so you will feel at home, but they are not the convention.

Note the list iteration with .each(key, value)

This will work:

```
Map service_name_status = ['a-service':'INSTALL', 'b-service':'UPGRADE', 'C-service':'UPGRADE', 'D-service':'INSTALL']

service_name_status.each {SERVICE_NAME, HELM_COMMAND ->
    println "SERVICE_NAME=${SERVICE_NAME}"
    println "HELM_COMMAND=${HELM_COMMAND}"
}
```

EDIT:

The following can be used to convert that to a map. Be careful, the replaceAll part is fragile and depends on the data to always look the same.

```
//assuming you can have it in a string like this
String st = "[a-service=INSTALL, b-service=UPGRADE, C-service=UPGRADE, D-service=INSTALL]"
//this part is dependent on format
String mpStr = st.replaceAll(/\[/, "['")
                 .replaceAll(/=/, "':'")
                 .replaceAll(/]/, "']")
                 .replaceAll(/, /, "', '")
println mpStr
//convert the properly formatted string to a map
Map mp = evaluate(mpStr)
assert mp instanceof java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Comment: The list I have is something I can't control, so the map example isn't really helping enlse, I can convert the list to a map.

Comment: I added a sample that could get you started